# Calendar in wicket

Tags: java, calendar, wicket

I would like to have a small brief calendar in wicket.
DatePicker is a component which has textField, and calendar is being shown for short period of time, until you select date.
But I need permanent calendar, like in Outlook.
Wicket FullCalendar is very large for me, I need the one of datePicker format.
There is such component, or no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think, there's a readymade component in core wicket for that. But it should be pretty easy to roll your own. Here are a few ideas on that:

- Grab the DatePicker and extract the calender from there (Note that the DatePicker uses YUI internally).
- Have a look at the [WijCalendar component](http://code.google.com/p/wiquery-plugins/source/browse/trunk/wiquery-plugins/wiquery-wijmo/src/main/java/org/odlabs/wiquery/wijmo/wijcalendar/WijCalendar.java?r=211) from the WiQuery project
- just render the values as a table, apply CSS and let jQuery's Themeroller have a go.

Comment: I`m writing my own component now

Answer (score 1):

Recently I needed such a calendar widget too. But couldn't find one. The Wicket calendar picker is based on the [YUI component](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/calendar/index.html). Despite the base component supports inline display I couldn't find any parameter for the wicket date picker that triggers this mode.

Finally I came up with writing my own simple component. It uses the [JQueryUI calendar widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline).

Answer (score 1):

Take also a look at Webical project. It's written in Wicket and it has what you need in its GUI: http://code.google.com/p/webical/wiki/Screenshots